# imaxima: no LaTeX output and crash

Tags: latex, maxima

I want to setup the `imaxima` buffer with working LaTeX output. Following the [EmacsWiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MaximaMode), I added this to my init:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/")
(autoload 'maxima-mode "maxima" "Maxima mode" t)
(autoload 'imaxima "imaxima" "Frontend for maxima with Image support" t)
(autoload 'maxima "maxima" "Maxima interaction" t)
(autoload 'imath-mode "imath" "Imath mode for math formula input" t)
(setq imaxima-use-maxima-mode-flag t)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.ma[cx]" . maxima-mode))
```

I have `maxima` installed on my machine (Void Linux) and it runs fine in a shell. There are indeed `.el` files in `/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/`: `imaxima.el`, `maxima.el`, `imath.el` and others.

In Emacs, I launch `M-x imaxima` and land in a maxima buffer. There are two problems:

1. Everything crashes if I hit `Return` with no `;` character at the end of the line. Emacs becomes totally unresponsive and I have to kill it.
2. When I put the `;` character, there is an error message :

```
(%i1) 1 + 1;

LaTeX error in: 2
```

I have a `texlive` installation on my machine but perhaps `imaxima` runs the wrong command?

Has someone encountered these problems and has an example of a working configuration?

### Edit 1:

If I run emacs with `emacs 2> emacs-stderr.log`, I find that nothing gets written to stderr at all.

Comment: FWIW this (new and buggy) behaviour also happens in a Window 10 64 bit machine with GNU Emacs 27.1 (build 1, x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2020-08-21, with imaxima-setup.el file from Maxima 5.44.0 for windows. Also, the introduction of amsmath package in imaxima-latex-preamble has no effect. In this particular installation LaTeX distro is MikTeX 2.9.

Comment: Same here with a Linux Debian 10 machine. The introduction of amsmath in imaxima-latex-preamble did not help.

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly due to a known problem with package loading in texlive2020. Until this is fixed, a workaround would be to put:

```tex
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

in the emacs variable `imaxima-latex-preamble` to make sure this is loaded first.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem which was solved following instructions in: https://sourceforge.net/p/maxima/bugs/3687/
The solution is  replacing files as root: imaxima.el,  imath.el  and adding file mylatex.ltx.el in directory: /usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/maxima.
You can download the files in the given link.
Good luck.